# Block Diagram using Integrator (Linear Systems Theory - Hespanha)

Tags: control-engineering

This
[image]

Not sure what to do. At first I ignored what is said about using an integrator and drew the block diagram of the system, which looked a little complicated. So now, using just integrators I am stuck. If we try just taking the first system

x'1 = x1 + 4u

if we want to us an integrator, where y' = u, how can we ever draw this while satisfying the previous equation?

EDIT: Actually I think I got your hint. Is my system correct ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following block diagram. Note that your $\boldsymbol{D}=\boldsymbol{0}$.

[image]

If you really want to have all the states you could draw it like the following picture. You can neglect all gains with $1$, if gain blocks are not allowed (for whatever crazy reason) then you can replace them by an equivalent number of signals to the summation block. eg. gain of 3 for $x_2$ will be split into three separate lines all connected to the summation block.

[image]

Comment: i was expecting every block to be of type integrator

Comment: so is my 2nd diagram not correct in my original question above?

Comment: You should upload your pictures in the proper orientation. And you Block diagram is not correct, you have not gain blocks. Please have a look at my diagram.